# Omitting a repeated verb

Tags: ellipsis

What is the rule and meaning of ***does*** in the following sentence (I think the *appear* omitted by it but if I am wrong please correct the title and tag):

> The Moon illusion is an optical illusion which causes the Moon to *appear* larger near the 
>   horizon than it ***does*** higher up in the sky. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_illusion)

MORE EXAMPLES

1. Sound travels faster in liquids and non-porous solids than it does in air (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound).
2. This makes it possible for the Sun to rotate faster at its equator (about 25 days) than it does at more extreme latitudes (about 35 days near its poles) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun).
3. The Sun appears larger at sunrise than it does while higher in the sky, in a manner similar to the moon illusion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an interesting question. The facts seem simple enough:

**The author is saying *does* instead of *appears* because they don't want to repeat themselves.**

But you can come up with more than one theory to explain those facts:

1. In English, an auxiliary verb like *do* lets us omit the rest of a verb phrase:

   > Do you **like ice cream**?
   > Yes, I **like ice cream.**

   or

   > Do you **like ice cream**?
   > Yes, I **do** <s>*like ice cream*</s>.

   Adding the auxiliary verb *do* lets us omit the rest.  This is called **Post Auxiliary Ellipsis**.

   In my example, you could also say:

   > Yes, I **do** **like ice cream**.

   That is, you can add *do* without omitting the rest.  The ellipsis is optional.

   *Do* is appropriate without omission in this example because of the emphasis on whether the clause is true or not.  This is often the case in response to a yes-no question.  But in your example, things are a little different:

   > The Moon illusion is an optical illusion which causes the Moon to appear larger near the horizon than it **appears** higher up in the sky.
   >
   > The Moon illusion is an optical illusion which causes the Moon to appear larger near the horizon than it **does** <s>*appear*</s> higher up in the sky.

   We can replace *appear* with *does* and it sounds fine.  But if we add *does* without omitting *appear*, it sounds weird:

   > <sup>？</sup>The Moon illusion is an optical illusion which causes the Moon to appear larger near the horizon than it **does appear** higher up in the sky.

   I've marked this example with a <sup>？</sup> symbol to indicate that it's questionable.  In this case, adding emphasis on whether the clause is true or not is very strange―we're not answering a yes-no question, we're in the middle of a comparative construction ("X-er than" / "more X than").  Adding *does* here makes the sentence strange and hard to understand.

   By the way, remember that I called this **Post Auxiliary Ellipsis**, and not Post-*do* Ellipsis?  That's because any auxiliary works, not just *do*:

   > **Are** you **going to the store**?
   > Yes, I **am** <s>*going to the store*</s>.

   In this example, we already have the auxiliary *be*, so we use that one instead of adding *do*.
2. Of course, we could come up with another theory to explain the same facts.  What if we wanted to keep things as simple as possible?

   > The Moon illusion is an optical illusion which causes the Moon to appear larger near the horizon than it **appears** higher up in the sky.
   >
   > The Moon illusion is an optical illusion which causes the Moon to appear larger near the horizon than it **does** higher up in the sky.

   We could just say *does* replaces *appears*.  If we do that, we're calling *do* a **pro-verb**.  A pro-verb is like a pronoun, except it substitutes for verbs (or verb phrases) instead of nouns.  And in English, *do* is our pro-verb of choice.

   This explanation works pretty well, as long as we're willing to admit other auxiliaries as pro-verbs:

   > **Are** you **going to the store**?
   > Yes, I **am**.

   Now auxiliary *be* is a pro-verb substituting for the entire verb phrase *be going to the store*, at least according to the pro-verb theory.

So there's probably more than one way to answer your question.  These are just a couple ways of thinking about it.

Answer (score 4):

It’s the sense #23 in [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/DO):

> Used as an auxiliary to replace an earlier verb or a verb phrase to avoid repetition:
>
> He likes you as much as I do.