# "Language doesn't matter, feeling does" - is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

It seems there is no grammatical mistake in this sentence, but I am pretty much not sure of that.

> Language doesn't matter, feeling does.

Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Maybe use "feelings do" as several emotions usually come into play.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. This is an example of post-auxiliary ellipsis see: [Omitting a repeated verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/35288/omitting-a-repeated-verb)

As Morgan notes there is a semantic difference between "feeling" and "feelings". You should choose the correct word.

Some may argue for a semicolon instead of a comma (arguing that "Feelings do" is a complete utterance). I think both are acceptable.